# What is the benefit using php attributes rather than static method

Tags: php, php-8.1

I use custom php attribute in my entity class,

and then there are service that read this attribute to prepare configuration array.

Something like this

```
class User implements UserInterface {

    #[GridUi(label: 'ID')]
    private int id;

    #[GridUi(label: 'Email address')]
    private string email;

    #[GridUi(label: 'Full name')]
    private string fullname;

}
```

But then I wonder, why not use static method like this

```
class User implements UserInterface {

    private int id;

    private string email;

    private string fullname;

    public static function getGridUiConfig()
    {
        return [
            'columns' => [
                ['label' => 'ID', field: 'id'],
                ['label' => 'Email address', field: 'email'],
                ['label' => 'Full name', field: 'fullname'],
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Now I use php attribute because this feels like best practice.

But in this case, what is the benefit using php attributes rather than static method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example? There is no benefit. By all means, use a static method.

Remember, attributes are for *metadata* that describes something about a side-effect or behavior associated with the class/method/property. Not internal functionality.

For instance: Let's say you have a Controller class (common for routers and MVC paradigms). Let's also say that you want a particular piece of functionality to occur before or after a given route method within that class (ie: middleware).

Rather than defining your middleware internally on the class, or forcing your router to worry about the internals of each class that it's responsible for, you can use attributes that augment the behavior of your request/response lifecycle based on the presence of these attributes.

Basically, it's syntactic sugar to allow you to simply mark certain things that other areas of the application can respond to.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Yep, I choose the static method in this case because the attribute doesn't have any side effect on the entity.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 8 Attributes are a *design pattern* to add **syntactic metadata.**
Therefor there is no *technical* benefit, using them - afaik.

The actual benefits are,
Attributes

- can be namespaced
- can have zero or more parameters to it
- may resolve to class names
- Attribute class names can be imported with use statements
- There can be more than one Attribute to a declaration

---

Sticking to your example, it is obviously way more readable than the static function.

Its benefits exceed the difference shown in your example.
Personally, I'd say the best features are the **reusability** and **readability**.